# Customer email notification upon order update in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to send an email notification to the customer if the order has been updated by the admin. I want this to happen if the admin changed the order status to pending payment, and I want to include in the email the link for customer payment page like this:

```
www.mysite/checkout/order-pay/229/?pay_for_order=true&key=wc_order_5b2b9da4904a6
```

Is there any woocommerce hook that I can use to make this happen?

Comment: You can take a look at: https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-reminder-pro/18517459

Comment: @Castiblanco, thanks for the suggestion, but as much as possible I don't want to you a plugin, I want it to be fully customized.